# Why is anyValue % 1 "silly math" in Sonar when anyValue is a double?

Tags: java, sonarqube, modulus

SonarQube raises the major violation [Silly math should not be performed](https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/coding_rules#q=silly%20math) in my code. The description says

> Certain math operations are just silly and should not be performed
>   because their results are predictable.
>
> In particular, `anyValue` % 1 is silly because it will always return 0.

In my case though, `anyValue` is a double. And this works [as intended](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) for me. Here's the actual code:

```
double v = Double.parseDouble(Utils.formatDouble(Double.valueOf(value.getValue()), accuracy.intValue()));
boolean negative = v < 0;
v = Math.abs(v);
long deg = (long) Math.floor(v);

v = (v % 1) * 60;
```

Is the analyser assuming my variable is an `int` (which is their bug)? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: *sounds* like a bug on their side. Just for completion sake, can you show the exact code where you get the violation?

Comment: @pabrams why should it not?

Comment: Because there's nothing special about it... you should have a reason to upvote or downvote.  But whatever...  I guess I'm not being very productive by asking this question.

Comment: Am I missing something?  I thought anyvalue modulo 1 always returns 0; doesn't matter whether anyvalue is an int or float?

Comment: @pabrams - you are missing something. Go try it. Or read the spec I linked to.

Comment: I think they meant "results are predictable" that's why %1 is not recommended. because you would just remove anything before the decimal places left you with all the value after it. as for return 0 I think they meant for the math function below it.

Comment: @user3659052 no! what they are referring to is that for any integer the operation `integer%1` is useless because it always returns 0, for a floating point number on the other hand the result is not constant.

Comment: For those who don't get it: `7.4 % 1` is `0.4`. Well, it is `0.40000000000000036`, but that's because `double` is not necessarily an exact number.

Comment: @ire_and_cureses ah I see, I guess... seems non-intuitive to me, since  X /1 is (X + 0) even when X is float, but I'm no expert.

Comment: Looks like a bug, file a report on https://jira.sonarsource.com/ and either ignore the error for now, or use `v = (v - deg) * 60` in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Just wanted to sanity-check before blaming the tool.

Comment: Even if what Eugene wrote as an answer fixes the "bug", it is certainly the wrong / misleading error message and certainly some kind of bug on their side.

Comment: @luk2302 - Apparently I don't have permission to raise an issue, even after logging in. The [SonarQube Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/sonarqube) states that this tag is actively monitored here at SO, so I'll leave it for them to find.

Comment: And thanks I just found it ;) I'll file a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, so thanks a lot for reporting it.

The problem is here in the code : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/3.9/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/ConstantMathCheck.java#L117

where there is absolutely no check on the type of the left operand of the % operator.

I just filed the following bug to handle this : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1457

Answer (score 2):

You could make your expression more explicit by changing it to use explicit double constant like:

```
(v % 1.0d) * 60
```

Comment: `1.0` or `1d`. `1.0d` seems extraneous.

Comment: You are right. The double is the default and could be omitted. So as `0`.

Comment: This is a good idea. I've confirmed it removes the violation and is much more explicit. I will still raise this case with the developers.

Comment: In the end this is just a way to trick the tool, I would not modify my code to turn off a (wrong) violation. You can mark the issue as false positive in SonarQube interface.